# How to quickly create multi-page layout presentation? (image maps?)

Tags: website-design, tools

How to quickly create an interactive presentation of the layout where user can click buttons to navigate through the site.

Obvious solution from HTML side would be to use image maps, but these are very tiresome to make - any clue if there are generators allowing me to edit and create something similar, only along multiple pages? Preferably: free.

Comment: Adobe Edge is intended to be a tool that can make a usable interactive version of a site quite quickly, which can then be used like a testing presentation or interactive wireframe. It's not free, payment by subscription, and has a few flaws, but it might suit for your purposes since it sounds like you're wanting a walkthrough for testing not a final design. [Here's a writeup on it from another question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/16111/3327)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe Dreamweaver has a nice little tool for VERY quickly creating image maps, simply drag a rectangle where you want it, and add the target address to the html code.

I do this myself for the same reason you suggest, IE to create a quick mockup for a client.

(I know its not free, but most serious designers/developers have it)

Answer (score 1):

[Axure RP](http://www.axure.com/) is interactive wireframe software and gives you the ability to generate an interactive HTML website wireframe or UI mockup without coding. Then, send a link to clients or users to review. Or design an Android or iPhone app interface and view it on your mobile device.

Comment: Not to bad. Only 300$ is a little bit steep for a tool that will do for me a same thing imagemap can do.