# Tools and softwares need to learn to be a web and graphics designer

Tags: website-design

This is my first question here. I am in my academic level. I know html, and a bit of css. I want my career in graphics and web design. As a startup, other than Html and css how many tools and softwares do i need to learn? Is knowing Javascript is mandatory for this filed?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16107/is-there-graphic-design-software-made-for-beginners-suitable-for-designing-webs and http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31/tips-and-resources-for-beginning-designers

Comment: @Scott, somewhat help full. 1st link doesn't meet my question, the 2nd link is based on which websites to search for tutorials. I asked about tools and softwares which i need to learn for web designing and graphics.

Comment: Amit, the first link answers that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a career in web design, some tools (not a complete list, but the most common) that you will need are as follows:

- Overall graphic design: Photoshop
- Icons and other vectors: Illustrator, Corel draw, Inkscape
- HTML authoring: Dreamweaver
- Text editing software: Sublime text, brackets

Learning javascript along with graphic design will give you an edge in web design.

HTH>

Comment: The exact answer I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Amit do not go and learn Dreamweaver pointless

Comment: @joojaa, Thanks for the advice but what I just saw on web that Dreamweaver is a web page developing tool without writing code. Why its pointless?

Comment: @Amit beacuse thats not how web has been developed since 2000. Anything you do in Dreamweaver will be a mess that is useless for web devs,

Comment: @joojaa, then why after 15 years this tool still is in talks? And I have heard that web designing companies do ask for knowledge in Dreamweaver? Why so? I am just asking as I do not know regarding the matter so well.

Comment: @Amit companies also ask for knowledge in COBOL and that is technology form 1959, and in general Cobol has a lot of code to maintain but not much of a future. Companies need outdated skills too! Anyway if you know how to do stuff by hand you know how to do it in Dreamweaver

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25056/discussion-between-amit-and-joojaa).

Comment: Dreamweaver is like a WYSIWYG Editor. You can drag and drop stuff and the result is going to be HTML. But if you want to write semantic correct code, you better learn HTML and write the code with Notepad++